# Why 'BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask.java' does not work in ionic?

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm working on background processes and currently using [cordova's background fetch plugin](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-plugin-background-fetch) in **ionic**. I want to run my background task even when I terminate my app. It works in iOS but the [documentation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-plugin-background-fetch) says it also supports **android**. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-plugin-background-fetch), in order to make `enableHeadless: true` to work I need to write a java code and can place the BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask.java file anywhere in my app. After creating BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask.java file I'm still getting the default implementation for headless task.

I have also tried [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) but it stops the background process when I terminate my app. [cordova-plugin-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-plugin-background-fetch) meets my all requirements so that's why I'm sticking with it for now. I have currently placed my java file in:

> myProjectFolder/www/src/android/BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask.java

Here's my code:

## JS code

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
  var BackgroundFetch = window.BackgroundFetch;
  function background() {
    var fetchCallback = function() {
      console.log('[js] BackgroundFetch event received');
      BackgroundFetch.finish();
    };
    var failureCallback = function(error) {
      console.log('- BackgroundFetch failed', error);
    };
    BackgroundFetch.configure(fetchCallback, failureCallback, {
      minimumFetchInterval: 15, // <-- default is 15
      stopOnTerminate: false,
      enableHeadless: true
    });
  }
});
```

## Java Code

```
package com.transistorsoft.cordova.backgroundfetch;
import android.content.Context;
import com.transistorsoft.tsbackgroundfetch.BackgroundFetch;
import android.util.Log;

public class BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask implements HeadlessTask {
    @Override
    public void onFetch(Context context) {
        Log.d(BackgroundFetch.TAG, "My BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask:  onFetch");
        // Perform your work here.
        Log.d(BackgroundFetch.TAG, "Yes, I am running");

        // Just as in Javascript callback, you must signal #finish
        BackgroundFetch.getInstance(context).finish();
    }
}
```

## config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <resource-file src="www/src/android/BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask.java" target="src/com/transistorsoft/cordova/backgroundfetch/BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask.java" />
</platform>
```

What I want to get is:

```
08-31 12:13:07.722  1169  1169 D TSBackgroundFetch: - My BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask:  onFetch
08-31 12:13:07.741  1169  1169 D TSBackgroundFetch: - Yes, I am running
```

And what I'm getting is this:

```
08-31 11:43:07.654 27610 27610 D TSBackgroundFetch: - Background Fetch event received
08-31 11:43:07.665 27610 27610 D TSBackgroundFetch: - finish
08-31 11:43:07.665 27610 27610 D TSBackgroundFetch: - jobFinished
08-31 11:43:07.689 27610 27610 D TSBackgroundFetch: HeadlessJobService onStartJob
08-31 11:43:07.690 27610 27610 D TSBackgroundFetch: BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask onFetch -- DEFAULT IMPLEMENTATION
08-31 11:43:07.690 27610 27610 D TSBackgroundFetch: - finish
08-31 11:43:07.690 27610 27610 D TSBackgroundFetch: HeadlessJobService jobFinished
08-31 11:58:07.452 27610 27610 D TSBackgroundFetch: - Background Fetch event received
08-31 11:58:07.452 27610 27610 D TSBackgroundFetch: - finish
08-31 11:58:07.452 27610 27610 D TSBackgroundFetch: - jobFinished
08-31 11:58:07.482 27610 27610 D TSBackgroundFetch: HeadlessJobService onStartJob
08-31 11:58:07.482 27610 27610 D TSBackgroundFetch: BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask onFetch -- DEFAULT IMPLEMENTATION
08-31 11:58:07.482 27610 27610 D TSBackgroundFetch: - finish
```

Is there any solution to this problem or any other alternative to cordova-plugin-background-fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the default processing of the plug-in is being executed.
Check if BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask.java under the platform has been overwritten.
If it is not overwritten, the target path is incorrect.
target="src/com/transistorsoft/cordova/backgroundfetch/BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask.java"

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have already solved the problem but forgot that I have posted my question here, as I'm not an active user. You are right though. I just changed target of 'BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask.java' in config.xml and my problem was solved there.

Comment: @BlueAce. l am the same issue and l fixed the path. But l didn't get `TSBackgroundFetch: - My BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask:  onFetch` . Could you please give us full code . Thank you

Comment: @AliGhassan Sorry for the late reply, I just changed the `target` in `<resource-file src="www/src/android/BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask.java" target="src/com/transistorsoft/cordova/backgroundfetch/BackgroundFetchHeadlessTask.java" />`.
Can't remember the correct target  address now, as it was too long ago.

Comment: @BlueAce . Thanks for replying.  he is working fine after terminating the app.  but he doesnt run any data like fetch data json from url .